# Letter and number gesture in iphone

Tags: ios, view, touch, uigesturerecognizer, gesture-recognition

I tried searching a lot but couldn't come across a solution.

Is there any open source code or iOS provides something to detect gesture for alphabet characters and numeric letters on view?

alphabet characters = A/a, B/b to Z/z).
numeric letters = 1, 2 to 9.

Comment: hi did you get something for this ?
Any references ?